# Issue mapping code first inherited navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-relationship

When I try to generate a database using codefirst with inehrited navigation properties I get an error:

**error 0040: Type Point_Countries is not defined in namespace <strike>xx.xxx</strike> (Alias=Self).**

I have 3 classes

```
public class PointBase
{
    public int PointID { get; set; }
    public virtual Point Point { get; set; }
}

public class Point
{
    public int PointID { get; set; }
    public DbGeography Data { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Country> Countries { get; set; }
}

public Country : PointBase
{
    public int CountryID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Afterwards, I created an EntityTypeConfiguration for point

```
internal class PointMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Point>
{
    public PointMap()
    {
        HasMany(x => x.Countries).WithRequired(x => x.Point).HasForeignKey(x => x.PointID);
    }
}
```

I can't seem to figure out why this error shows up...